# Posting to posterous.com through posterous api

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl and i want to post through posterous api. I am using this method posterous.com/api/newpost

My code is

```
$url="userid"
$posturl = "posterous.com/api/newpost";
$session = curl_init($posturl);
$postVars = array(

"site_id" => $url,

"body"=>$message        

);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
curl_close($session);
```

But I am getting this error

```
<rsp stat="fail">
 <err code="3001" msg="Invalid Posterous email or password" />
</rsp>
```

Please guide me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well you don't actually seem to be sending an email address or password, so I guess that's the problem.

> All calls require user authentication
>   which is done by basic HTTP
>   authentication with a user's Posterous
>   email address and password.

You can do it like this:

```
$user = 'foo@bar.com';
$password = 'foobar';

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);
```

Comment: Hi,
But how can i send this details there is no such mention in the api method ?

Comment: HI, But after providing the authentication details same error is still occuring

Comment: Why dont you simply send an normal email to post@posterous.com.. would be simply, doesnt it?

Comment: It actually IS in their API docs:
All calls require user authentication which is done by basic HTTP authentication with a user's Posterous email address and password.